# Can you explain what this code does?

Tags: android, image-processing

This code is used to compress and resize image in my app Image is showing blurry and   size is reducing to much. Can yo Explain how this code works and how can i improve quality of my image with this existing code.

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;

            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                    && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            Bitmap bit1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),
                    null, o2);
```

Comment: increase `REQUIRED_SIZE` obviously. It is resized to that size.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thanks bro. it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is just initializing the bitmap options to work with a decodedStream ( the input image or file you will work with) after that is setting a rule thats say the required size should be >= 200 width and height and after that is just creating a final bitmap with the required output of the stream

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;

            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                    && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            Bitmap bit1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),
                    null, o2);
bit1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); //you can use this line and play with the value 100 in order to set quality of the image when its compresed
```

Since your image is scaled to a certain size ( which is >= 200 width and height) your image output dimension will depend on the input bitmap at first

if you want to check out the Dimensions of the bitmap you can do this

```
Log.e("Dimensions", bit1.getWidth()+" "+bit1.getHeight());
```

**Bitmap.compress**

> compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream
>   stream) Write a compressed version of the bitmap to the specified
>   outputstream.

EDIT: As  Vladyslav Matviienko suggests you could increase your REQUIRED_SIZE to a bigger value, since like i wrote above, you are setting a fixed size at first

Comment: I am doing this "bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);" . Using png format can improve image quality ?

Comment: you can change to jpg if you want, no need of png

Comment: i increase required size and it worked for me. thanks

Comment: Glad it helped, any questions feel free to ask